# How to repeat a calculation in the same cell for different values. EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to run this formula `-MAX(MIN(Y,B)-MAX(X,A),0)` to subtract from a value Z. However, I want to run the same subtraction for different values of (X,Y) like:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| K | L |
| M | N |
| O | P |

...

without just copy pasting the same formula for n pairs of (X,Y). (i.e:`-MAX(MIN(L,B)-MAX(K,A),0)-MAX(MIN(N,B)-MAX(M,A),0)...)`

Is there a way to do this with just using formulas?

Any help is much appreciated!

I can do it with just copy pasting the same functions and make a gigantic formula but I was wondering if there is a smart way of doing this.

Edit: I just want one result.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think it would help to have some sample data and your expected output, Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Which Excel version are you using?

Comment: You should show sample data and expected output. Now it is not clear whether you want 3 separate results or one Z - function(x1,y1) - function(x2,y2) - function (x3,y3)

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I just want one result, so the latter in user11222393's comment.

Comment: Do you want to substract -MAX(MIN(Y,B)-MAX(X,A),0) from Z so double negative ( z- (-MAX(MIN(Y,B)-MAX(X,A),0)), or just Z -MAX(MIN(Y,B)-MAX(X,A),0) -MAX(MIN(N,B)-MAX(M,A),0)

Comment: The latter again sir. Like the example I gave above where it would become a gigantic formula.

Comment: Added answer. Will work with Excel 365

Comment: Let me know if i should delete my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
=C2-SUM(MAP(E2:E6,F2:F6,LAMBDA(a,b,MAX(MIN(b,B2)-MAX(a,A2),0))))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I already made a version just manually copy pasting and used the formula you provided but your formula is giving me slightly off results. I'm probably making a mistake somewhere because the formula above should be doing exactly the same thing. I'll try to get it to work. Again, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Paste data sample and expected result with values coordinates and we will help you to adapt and debug

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly then I think this scenario sums it up.

[image]

If the above is what you want then please read on else let me know in comments and I will delete the answer.

The problem is that `Min` and `Max` function can take an array as an argument but it **will never return an array**. It will always return a single value.

The convoluted formula I created is

`=SUM(-IF(((B1:B5*(B1:B5<Y1:Y5))+(Y1:Y5*(B1:B5>=Y1:Y5)))-((A1:A5*(A1:A5>X1:X5))+(X1:X5*(A1:A5<=X1:X5)))>0,((B1:B5*(B1:B5<Y1:Y5))+(Y1:Y5*(B1:B5>=Y1:Y5)))-((A1:A5*(A1:A5>X1:X5))+(X1:X5*(A1:A5<=X1:X5))),0))`

**PS**: Once you confirm that this is what you want then I will update my answer with more explanation on how I reached at this formula.

**[Download Sample File](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/5wc9uch4emf4of9v5j7s1/stuffandmorestuff-Example.xlsx?rlkey=4bl3j70vuvdzhvet1i062nqhd&dl=0)**

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't want to use a helper column?

[image]

Notice your formula `MAX(MIN(Y,B)-MAX(X,A),0)` will **always** return a positive number or zero. So just sump up that column and then do your substraction.

My formula in column C is:

```
=MAX(MIN(B7;$B$2)-MAX(A7;$B$1);0)
```

Formula in cell B4:

```
=B3-SUM(C7:C11)
```